# Write macro to file at runtime and \input the content

Tags: macros, external-files

Let me give it as an example:

I want to write some commands to a file

```
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=mycommands
\immediate\write\tempfile{"\toprule"}%Yes it don't work like this!
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
```

Then somewhere after:

```
\begin{tabular}{r l l l l l l l}
\input{mycommands}%add toprule here
```

Comment: Why do you want to write this to a file? If it's just contents you need to create during runtime you could as well define a global macro that stores the contents.

Comment: My problem is different, the above case is just an example.

Comment: In that case it might be a good idea to explain your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must prevent expansion when writing to the file. And you can't use \input to load the file if it starts e.g. with a \toprule: `\input` is not expandable and so not allowed in this place. The primitive input command will work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=mycommands.txt
\immediate\write\tempfile{\unexpanded{\toprule}}%
\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\begin{tabular}{r l l l l l l l}
\csname @@input\endcsname mycommands.txt
abc\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```